# Javascript - Draw Pattern

Tags: javascript, arrays

> Construct the following pattern in a X by X grid(Multidimensional array)
> X should be an odd number

```
ooxoo
oxxxo
xxxxx
oxxxo
ooxoo
```

> Example :
> Input X = 5 should return

```
[["o","o","x","o","o"],
 ["o","x","x","x","o"],
 ["x","x","x","x","x"],
 ["o","x","x","x","o"],
 ["o","o","x","o","o"]]
```

> Return type should be a object.

So far I have written this code but it does not correctly provide the result I am looking for.

```js
function drawPattern(X) {
  // Create an empty grid
  var grid = [];

  // Calculate the middle of the grid
  var middle = Math.floor(X / 2);

  // Loop through each row of the grid
  for (var i = 0; i < X; i++) {
    // Create an empty row
    var row = [];

    // Loop through each column of the row
    for (var j = 0; j < X; j++) {
      // Check if the current position is on the edge of the grid
      if (i == 0 || i == X - 1 || j == 0 || j == X - 1) {
        // If the current position is on the edge, add an "o" to the row
        row.push("o");
      } else {
        // If the current position is not on the edge, check if it is in the middle of the grid
        if (i == middle && j == middle) {
          // If the current position is in the middle, add an "x" to the row
          row.push("x");
        } else {
          // If the current position is not in the middle, add an "o" to the row
          row.push("o");
        }
      }
    }

    // Add the row to the grid
    grid.push(row);
  }

  // Return the grid
  return grid;
}
console.log(drawPattern(5).join("\n"))
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please do so next time

Comment: What is the expected output if X = 7?

Comment: @Yogi `oooxooo
ooxxxoo
oxxxxxo
xxxxxxx
oxxxxxo
ooxxxoo
oooxooo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea here is to calculate the distance from the middle (where distance doesn't allow diagonals) and then fill in x if it's close enough or o if it's not.

To put it another way, the outer edge of the 'x's should always be the same number of moves (excluding diagonals) from the center of the square so if the point you're at is at that distance or closer it should be an x otherwise an o.

```js
// the distance from one point to another, assuming we can only move
// left or right and up or down
const distance = (point_a, point_b) =>
  // distance left and right
  Math.abs(point_a[0] - point_b[0]) +
    // distance up and down
    Math.abs(point_a[1] - point_b[1]);

const make_pattern = (side_length) => {
  const halfish_length = Math.floor(side_length / 2);
  const middle = [halfish_length, halfish_length];
  
  return Array.from(
    { length: side_length },
    (_, row_i) => Array.from(
      { length: side_length },
      (_, col_i) => distance(middle, [col_i, row_i]) > halfish_length ? 'o' : 'x'
    )
  );
};

const draw_pattern = (side_length) =>
  make_pattern(side_length)
    .map((row) => row.join(''))
    .join("\n");

console.log(draw_pattern(5));
console.log(draw_pattern(7));
```

For loop version:

```js
const distance = (point_a, point_b) =>
  Math.abs(point_a[0] - point_b[0]) + Math.abs(point_a[1] - point_b[1]);

const make_pattern = (side_length) => {
  const halfish_length = Math.floor(side_length / 2);
  const middle = [halfish_length, halfish_length];
  
  let rows = [];
  
  for(let row_i = 0; row_i < side_length; row_i++) {
    let cols = [];
    
    for(let col_i = 0; col_i < side_length; col_i++)
      cols.push( distance(middle, [col_i, row_i]) > halfish_length ? 'o' : 'x' );
    
    rows.push(cols);
  }
  
  return rows;
};

const draw_pattern = (side_length) =>
  make_pattern(side_length)
    .map((row) => row.join(''))
    .join("\n");

console.log(draw_pattern(5));
console.log(draw_pattern(7));
```

References:

- [Array.from() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Comment: Could you add some comments?

Comment: @Tarik I've added a couple of comments, not really sure what to add; the for loop version and the Array.from() reference probably explain Array.from().

Comment: I do not find this easy to read or grasp compared to either of my versions.

Answer (score 1):

If you do it one line at a time and fluctuate the sides:

```js
function drawPattern(X) {
  // Create an empty grid
  const grid = [];
  // Calculate the middle of the grid
  let middle = left = right = Math.floor(X / 2); // works because arrays are 0 based
  // Loop through each row of the grid
  for (let i = 0; i < X; i++) {
    // Create an empty row
    const row = [];
    // Loop through each column of the row
    let j = 0;
    for (; j < left; j++)   row.push("o"); // from 0 to left
    for (; j <= right; j++) row.push("x"); // from where we are now to right
    for (; j < X; j++)      row.push("o"); // from where we are now to end
    // Add the row to the grid
    grid.push(row.join('')); // join the items
    // count up or down
    left += i<middle ? -1 : 1; // how far down? if less than the middle move left
    right += i<middle ? 1 : -1; // how far down? if less than the middle move right
  }
  // Return the grid
  return grid.join('\n'); // join the rows
}
console.log(drawPattern(5))
console.log(drawPattern(7))
```

Using spread and Array.from and mirror the Os

```js
const drawPattern = X => {
  // Calculate the middle of the grid
  let middle = oLen = Math.floor(X / 2); // works because arrays are 0 based
  // Loop through each row of the grid using Array.from and map
  return Array.from({ length: X }).map((_, i) => {
    const o = Array.from({length:oLen}).fill("o");       // fill from start
    const x = Array.from({length:X-(oLen*2)}).fill("x"); // fill from last o
    oLen += i < middle ? -1 : 1;    
    return [...o,...x,...o] // spread to get copy - last o is repeat of first o
    .join('');   // join items 
  }).join('\n'); // join rows
};
console.log(drawPattern(5))
console.log(drawPattern(7))
```

Comment: Clever answer. I guess you need to add more comments for common mortals to understand your code.

Comment: @Tarik I like my second version more :)

Answer (score 0):

I have broken up the code into manageable pieces. The key into solving this type of problem is to break it into subproblems.

```js
// Generate a single row
function getRow(c1, n, c2, m) {
    const row = [];

    // Generate left side consisting of n characters
    for (let i=0; i<n; i++)
      row.push(c1);
  
    // Generate middle consisting of m characters
    for (let i=0; i<m; i++)
      row.push(c2);

    // Generate right side consisting of n characters 
    for (let i=0; i<n; i++)
      row.push(c1);
  
  return row;
}

// Generate grid data
function getGrid(c1, c2, p) {
    let grid = [];

    // Generate rows starting with 1 character in the middle
    // until p characters in the middle. 
    for (let i=1; i<=p; i+=2) {
        let m = i;
        let n = (p - i) / 2;
        let row = getRow(c1, n, c2, m);
        grid.push(row);
    }
  
    // Generate the second part of the grid's rows starting
    // at p-2 characters to avoid repeating the middle row
    // until 1 single character is left in the middle row.
    for (let i=p-2; i>=1; i-=2) {
        let m = i;
        let n = (p - i) / 2;
        let row = getRow(c1, n, c2, m);
        grid.push(row);
    }
  
    return grid;
}


function prettyPrint(grid) {
    for (const row of grid)
      console.log(row.join(''));
}

console.log('Printing patterns:');
prettyPrint(getGrid('o', 'x', 5));
console.log('');
prettyPrint(getGrid('o', 'x', 7));

console.log('Printing raw data:');
console.log(getGrid('o', 'x', 5));
console.log('');
console.log(getGrid('o', 'x', 7));
```

Comment: Your code works but is impossible to decipher without comments. Looks non-dry

Comment: @mplungjan Added comments to clarify the code as you recommended. To avoid code repetition in getRow, I could create a function that appends a given number of a single character to a given array. Arguably, I find this to be an overkill. Furthermore, I rather avoid creating functions with side effects.

Comment: I still think your code is overkill and has very poor variable names that does not help

Comment: @mplungjan You are right

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this code (a very simplify version to play with)

Hope this demonstration educates you to solve future problems! Main guidelines:

- when having an information (direction, how many characters to draw, etc.) - use variables
- try to make a long and inefficient code that solves the problem
- test the edges (for instance: what happens if size = 1) and refine your code
- consider make it better in terms of performance

Happy coding

```js
const matrix = []
const size = 5 // control the size of the matrix

let start = parseInt(size / 2) // control the start point - in your case the middle
let count = 1 // control how many `x`s are we going to draw
let direction = -1 // control the direction of drawing

for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  const row = []

  for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
    // as long as j is inside the drawing range - draw `x`
    row.push(j >= start && j < start + count ? 'x' : 'o')
  }

  start += direction // update start position for next line

  if (start < 0) { // if we need to change direction
    direction *= -1
    start += 2
  }

  count = count - direction * 2

  matrix.push(row)
}

console.log(matrix.join('\n')) // you should use a better printing method if you want a nice draw of the matrix
```

Comment: It does not work. See the output

Comment: fixed now. enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

This solution constructs a pattern in a X by X grid (multidimensional array) where X is an odd number. The function `drawPattern` takes an odd integer `x` as input and returns the desired pattern as a multidimensional array.

```
function drowPattern(x) {
  if (x % 2 === 0) {
    return "X should be an odd number";
  }

  const pattern = [];
  const center = Math.floor(x / 2);

  for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    const row = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < x; j++) {
      if (i === center && j === center) {
        row.push("x");
      } else if (Math.abs(i - center) + Math.abs(j - center) <= center) {
        row.push("x");
      } else {
        row.push("o");
      }
    }
    pattern.push(row);
  }

  return pattern;
}

drowPattern(5);
```